# No sound through Mac speakers

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, audio

This happened today when  at work I plugged in an external speakers jack, speakers were playing, everything was OK. But after I took the jack off, I couldn't hear any sound from the Mac speakers. It seems like disabled. So now I only can listen music through headphones or external speakers but not Mac speakers.

Here are a few screenshots:

> **Headphones jack in:**
>
> Top Menu Icon:
>
> [image: Jack In]
>
> When I press the increase sound button on
>   the keyboard:
>
> [image: Jack In]
>
> Sound Settings:
>
> [image: Jack In]
>
> **Headphones jack out:**
>
> Top Menu Icon:
>
> (image not available anymore)
>
> When I press the increase sound button on
>   the keyboard:
>
> [image: Jack Out]
>
> Sound Settings:
>
> [image: Jack Out]
>
> **If you had a similar situation or you know how to solve this, please do not
>   hesitate and help me ;)**

BTW, I've tried to repair permissions and restart the Mac (a few times), this didn't help.

Comment: That last sentence... "Did you try turning it off and turning it on again?" :-D

Comment: yes, i have tried this :D as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when your Mac thinks that a mini-TOSLINK device is plugged into the jack. (If you look, you'll be able to see a glowing red light inside). The volume can't be adjusted by the computer with digital audio, which is why you are unable to adjust it. If a restart doesn't help, it could be that there is excessive dust or dirt inside the speaker jack. Try cleaning it out with some compressed air; it's helped me many times in the past.

Comment: yes I see the red light inside of it. Ok I will try to clean it out, let you know if it helped.

Comment: Yes it fixed the problem!!!! than you very much dude ;)

Comment: Im embarrassed always when I see him answering questions I dont have an idea of. Guess you'll be a good IT expert purple. :)

Comment: 's what I'm here for, @Lukas! And thanks @Shiki, I most certainly hope to be one day!